# How to avoid primary key violation while doing inserts

Tags: insert, primary-key, deadlock, error-handling

I have a code which does insert into destination table from source, but at times we are ending up with deadlocks.

Due to deadlock , I have to rerun this code again.

while i do re-run , I end up with Primary key violation. Hence I want to add a check to insert only those rows which doesn't exist.

Can some help me with Tsql for this please

```
    declare @batchSize int = 1000
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destinationtable]
       ([PacketId]
       ,[DeviceId]
       ,[PacketDate]
       ,[PacketNumber]
       ,[Processed]
       ,[CreateDate]
       ,[NewReadingId])
 SELECT top (@batchSize)
       [PacketId]
      ,[DeviceId]
      ,[PacketDate]
      ,[PacketNumber]
      ,[Processed]
      ,[CreateDate]
      ,newid()
  FROM [dbo].[SourceTable]
  where Processed is null 
  order by CreateDate
```

Error message when i run after deadlock

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_packetid'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.destinationtable'. The duplicate key value is (1234567).​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use not exists

```
declare @batchSize int = 1000
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destinationtable]
   ([PacketId]
   ,[DeviceId]
   ,[PacketDate]
   ,[PacketNumber]
   ,[Processed]
   ,[CreateDate]
   ,[NewReadingId])
SELECT top (@batchSize)
   [PacketId]
  ,[DeviceId]
  ,[PacketDate]
  ,[PacketNumber]
  ,[Processed]
  ,[CreateDate]
  ,newid()
FROM [dbo].[SourceTable]
where Processed is null  
  and not exists (select 1 from [Destinationtable] 
                  where [PacketId] = [SourceTable].[PacketId])
order by CreateDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something wrong with the transaction that inserts data and updates processed, they should be atomic. On error, you should rollback the transaction and be on safe ground, so you can restart the transaction.

However, you can try MERGE:

```
MERGE [dbo].[Destinationtable] as x
USING (
    SELECT top (@batchSize) [PacketId]
    ,[DeviceId]
    ,[PacketDate]
    ,[PacketNumber]
    ,[Processed]
    ,[CreateDate]
    ,newid()
    FROM [dbo].[SourceTable]
    where Processed is null 
    order by CreateDate
) y 
    ON x.<key> = <y.key>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (<columns>)
    VALUES (...);
```